# Truffle Contracts deploy with name undefined

Tags: truffle, truffle-deployment

Whenever I `truffle deploy` my smart contracts, I get a message "duplicate contract names found for undefined". When I then try to interact with them, I get `ReferenceError: <contract name> is undefined`, for every contract I have deployed.

I'm unable to use 'truffle compile' because of a fairly restrictive work proxy, so I'm using a custom .js script from [here](https://levelup.gitconnected.com/compiling-ethereum-smart-contracts-locally-0-5-2-0-5-x-ebfea0aed3a9) and running it with `node compile`. The contracts are also from that page- `contract Dog` and `contract DogCollection`. When I deploy, I use `truffle deploy --compile-none` to have it deploy the bytecode I've already compiled. I'm guessing this is where the error comes in. How can I modify how the contract names are defined when generating the bytecode?

```
$ node solcjs --version
0.5.16+commit.9c3226ce.Emscripten.clang

$ truffle version
Truffle v5.3.3 (core: 5.3.3)
Solidity v0.5.16 (solc-js)
Node v10.19.0
Web3.js v1.3.5
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue was determined to be in the compile.js script used as a potential workaround. There is a better workaround that actually solves this issue:

Go to https://github.com/ethereum/solc-bin/tree/gh-pages/bin and download your relevant Solidity version compiler. Move this to ~/.config/truffle/compilers/node_modules. This will allow Truffle to use that compiler as part of its built-in `compile` command, and it will deploy correctly.